# Field in MS Access query can not be formated

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

One field in my query (`DSum("AuM","tbl_Client","Portfolio='" & [Portfolio] & "'") AS PortfolioAuM`) can not be formated.

I have tried:

1. Setting the format of the field in the query by going to properties
   and setting the desired format there. It does not take. Stranger
   still, I do not consistently have the option to select the
   formatting in properties. Sometimes it shows up, other times it
   gives me a blank and empty dropdown box from which i can not select    anything.
2. Manually setting a format by writing `#'##0.0` in the `Format` field property.
3. Writing the Format directly into my query using `Format(DSum("AuM","tbl_Client","Portfolio='" & [Portfolio] & "'")
   AS PortfolioAuM,'#'##.0')`
4. Formating the field not in the query, but only in the form that the query was built for.
5. Reformating the underlying data as a `Double`

None of these attempts worked. **How can I format this field? Why does this happen?**

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT tbl_Client.CIF, tbl_Client.Portfolio, 
    tbl_Criteria_Comp.Buyer_Review_StatusID, 
    tbl_Criteria_Comp.Comp_Review_StatusID, 
    tbl_Criteria_Tax.Tax_review_StatusID, 
    tbl_Client.AuM, 
    DSum("AuM","tbl_Client","Portfolio='" & [Portfolio] & "'") AS PortfolioAuM, 
    tbl_Client.BuyersReviewStatus, 
    [AuM]/[PortfolioAuM] AS AuMPoT, 
    tbl_Client.EntryDateReview
FROM 
    (tbl_Client INNER JOIN tbl_Criteria_Comp ON tbl_Client.CIF = tbl_Criteria_Comp.CIF) 
    INNER JOIN tbl_Criteria_Tax ON tbl_Client.CIF = tbl_Criteria_Tax.CIF;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing your SQL expression to the following in order to avoid the use of the `DSum` function:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_Client.CIF, 
    tbl_Client.Portfolio, 
    tbl_Criteria_Comp.Buyer_Review_StatusID, 
    tbl_Criteria_Comp.Comp_Review_StatusID, 
    tbl_Criteria_Tax.Tax_review_StatusID, 
    tbl_Client.AuM, 
    t.PortfolioAuM,
    tbl_Client.BuyersReviewStatus, 
    [AuM]/[t.PortfolioAuM] AS AuMPoT, 
    tbl_Client.EntryDateReview
FROM 
    (
        (
            tbl_Client INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT Portfolio, SUM(AuM) AS PortfolioAuM
                FROM tbl_Client
                GROUP BY Portfolio
            ) t
            ON tbl_Client.Portfolio = t.Portfolio
        )
        INNER JOIN tbl_Criteria_Comp ON tbl_Client.CIF = tbl_Criteria_Comp.CIF
    ) 
    INNER JOIN tbl_Criteria_Tax ON tbl_Client.CIF = tbl_Criteria_Tax.CIF;
```

This should retain the datatype of the `AuM` field and hence permit you to use the standard formatting options.

Comment: That worked. Thank you for the solution. Any idea why the other version does not work? Or can you explain to me why yours does work?

Comment: @rohrl77 I rarely use `DSum` in queries, but I think the difference may be due to the fact that your use of `DSum` will be evaluated as records are processed, whereas the data-type returned by the subquery in my example is known to Access in advance. Others may be able to offer a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The correct format part in SQL Query should be

```
SELECT 
    [...]
    Format(DSum("AuM","tbl_Client","Portfolio='" & [Portfolio] & "'"),'#,#0.0') AS PortfolioAuM
    [...]
```

I also think that modifing the SQL Query is the best Idea.